# Installing and making python packages universally available

Tags: python-3.x, pip, debian

I want to install some python packages, say `numpy`, `pyyaml` etc on `debian11`.

I want to these become available **for all users**.

Do I need to be a `root` or just `pip install numpy` will do the work?

(assuming no `virtualenv` is used)